# Joining multiple unsorted text files

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a number of single-column text files containing unsorted values. The aim is to join them, however, the "join" utility of linux requires the files to be sorted. Any idea how to do that without sorting?

A.txt

```
0000;
0001;
0002;
0003;
```

B.txt

```
0000;
0011;
0012;
0003;
```

C.txt

```
0000;
0024;
0003;
0025;
```

Desired Output:

```
0000;
0003;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the files you have and the expected output?

Comment: just included an example.

Comment: From which file do you want the common lines ordered by? In your example, A, B, and C have the common lines in the same order, but presumably this need not be the case?

Comment: No matter. Assume that the order in A is our choice.

Comment: This does not look like a "join" to me, it looks more like finding the lines that are common to all the files... It could probably be done fairly easily with `awk`...

Comment: I am just looking for the functionality. No matter which command or utility is being used. I would appreciate it if you could share any thing comes to your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome the "number of files beforehand" and the "repetitive elements" problems of twalberg's fine awk program, I'd use the more verbose:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from sys import argv

# collect all lines from each file in their own set

sets = []
for path in argv[1:]:
    with open(path) as infile:
        s = set(infile.readlines())
        sets.append(s)

# find the common items in all sets

common = sets[0]
for s in sets[1:]:
    common = common.intersection(s)

# print the common items in the order they appear in the
# first file

with open(argv[1]) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line in common:
            common.remove(line) # prevents duplicates
            print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

This, I believe, requires GNU awk for the multidimensional array:

```
gawk '
    FNR == 1 {nfiles++}
    {seen[$1][FILENAME] = 1} 
    END {for (item in seen) if (length(seen[item]) == nfiles) print item}
' A.txt B.txt C.txt
```

```
0000;
0003;
```

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp solution:

```
(defvar hash-list
  (collect-each ((a *args*))
    (hash-construct '(:equal-based) (zip (get-lines (open-file a))))))

(if hash-list
  (dohash (key val [reduce-left hash-isec hash-list])
    (put-line key)))

$ txr join.tl
$ txr join.tl A.txt
0000;
0001;
0002;
0003;
$ txr join.tl A.txt B.txt C.txt
0000;
0003;
```